# How to convert a value into a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables

I have searched about this but can't seem to find exactly how to do it.  Is there a simple way to directly convert the value into a variable?  This illustration may help you understand my problem.

```
var a = "randomText";

var randomText = "someothervalue";
```

I have read about eval() but it says it's not recommended to use since it's 'evil'.

Please help. 
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set of data that you need to access by name, then use a proper data structure instead of floating a bunch of variables around. Use an object.

```
var someObject = {};
someObject['foo'] = 123;
var propertyName = 'foo';
alert(someObject[propertyName]);
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer and suggestion to use proper data structures.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a global variable:

```
var a = "randomText";
window[a] = "value_of_random_text";
```

Comment: +1 and if you're not working with globals, using square bracket notation on the current object in scope is the proper methodology.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use it without EVAL.

Anad Evals bad Side is Mostly with Injection.

dont Get Confused. Its Not Evil.

jQuery Uses This a Lot. (e.g. json...)

Comment: `eval` breaks scope, is very slow and complicates debugging. It *is* evil. jQuery doesn't use it a lot. It only uses it for JSON parsing when the browser doesn't have a proper JSON parser built in (and most browsers do these days).

Comment: @Quentin , Can you please explain : `Breaks Scope` ?

Comment: Using square bracket notation on the current object in scope is the proper methodology.

Comment: @RoyiNamir jQuery makes every attempt to avoid `eval` because it is not proper to use. It stoops to use it when absolutely no other means of unserializing JSON is available.  IMO, they should completely remove use of `eval` and warn devs to make the JSON API available where it is found not to be. On my projects, I always include Crockford's JSON API shim ahead of jQuery to ensure `eval` does not get used. It's worth the few extra bytes.

Answer (score 0):

eval("var " +a+ " = 'someothervalue';");

It shouldn't be "evil" in this case.

Comment: Using square bracket notation on the current object in scope is the proper methodology.